# Liquibase always generating changesets for creating/dropping index

Tags: java, database, maven, indexing, liquibase

I am just starting to use Liquibase and I am wondering:  why is it that when I run `./mvnw compile liquibase:diff` are change sets generated to first drop existing indexes and then recreate them if they already exist?

Ex:

```
 <changeSet author="me (generated)" id="1486157347995-13">
      <dropIndex indexName="my_idx" tableName="notification"/>
      <createIndex indexName="my_idx" tableName="notification">
         <column name="index_col"/>
      </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably out of "laziness".

This is a simple way to make sure the index created is the same (not only the name, but the columns used) than the one in the reference database.

It handles two diff cases in one:

- missing index name in the target db,
- same index name but with a different definition.

Comment: Great, thank you for your explanation.  If you have time - another question: how often should I be generating new changelogs?  Every time there is an update to the DB? Or can I just append small changes such as adding a new sequence or column onto an existing changelog?  Does it matter?  Thanks!

Comment: Personnally, I generate the diff each release. They are packaged as deliverables along the binaries. I find diffing during development is less useful since liquibase can build and update your schema directly on your dev db.